# Doubly-linked list serialization and deserialization on C#. How to improve code

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, doubly-linked-list

The task is to write functions for serialization and deserialization of a doubly linked list (without using third-party libraries and standard serialization tools), presented in this form:

```
class ListNode
{
    public ListNode Previous;
    public ListNode Next;
    public ListNode Random;
    public string Data;
}


class ListRandom
{
    public ListNode Head;
    public ListNode Tail;
    public int Count;
}
```

where `public ListNode Random` is a reference to a random item within the list.

My original solution looks like this:

```
class ListRandom
{
    public ListNode Head;
    public ListNode Tail;
    public int Count;

    private ListNode GetNodeAt(int index)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (ListNode currentNode = Head; currentNode.Next != null; currentNode = currentNode.Next)
        {   if (counter == index)
                return currentNode;
            counter++;
        }
        return new ListNode();
    }


    public void Serialize(Stream s)
    {
        Dictionary<ListNode, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<ListNode, int>();
        int id = 0;
        for (ListNode currentNode = Head; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.Next)
        {
            dictionary.Add(currentNode, id);
            id++;
        }
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(s))
        {
            for (ListNode currentNode = Head; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.Next)
            {
                writer.Write(currentNode.Data);
                writer.Write(dictionary[currentNode.Random]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("List serialized");

    }

    public void Deserialize(Stream s)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Tuple<String,int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<String, int>>();
        int counter = 0;
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(s))
        {
            while (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
            {
                String data = reader.ReadString();
                int randomId = reader.ReadInt32();
                dictionary.Add(counter, new Tuple<String, int>( data, randomId));
                counter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("File readed");
        }
        Count = counter;
        Head = new ListNode();
        ListNode current = Head;
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            current.Data = dictionary.ElementAt(i).Value.Item1;
            current.Next = new ListNode();
            if (i != this.Count - 1)
            {
                current.Next.Previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                Tail = current;
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
        for (ListNode currentNode = Head; currentNode.Next != null; currentNode = currentNode.Next)
        {
            currentNode.Random = GetNodeAt(dictionary.ElementAt(counter).Value.Item2);
            counter++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("List deserialized");
    }
```

The algorithm is as follows - when serializing, first I am going through the list, and creating a dictionary from an element of the list and a number, which will describe index of this element in the list.Next, I am writing to the file data from the node, and the number of the list item to which ListNode Random referred.
When deserializing, I am creating a dictionary from a number (index of the future element of the list), and a pair of String (data of the element) and int (index of the list element to which the ListNode Random will refer). Next, I am creating the list itself, filling it with data, but without assigning any values ​​to the ListNode Random, since it can refer to an element that does not exist at the moment. And in the last loop, assign each ListNode Random the desired link to the list item.

How can this code / algorithm be improved?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to convert your linked list to a regular collection like a list. Serialization formats like json and protobuf simply have a type for collection, i.e. a sequence of items. Without specifying how this should be stored, i.e array/list/linked-list. If the Random node does not need to be preserved you could simply re-assign it to any random node after the list has been deserialized. It is often useful to have one class for serialization, and another for runtime use, and this would allow you to convert between the formats.

What complicates the issue is your `Random` node. If this need to be preserved you are not serializing a simple doubly linked list, but a graph. In this case you will need to handle references somehow, probably by assigning ids to each node. The way you are doing it seems reasonable, it might be tweaked, but the overall approach looks to be sound.

I would however seriously consider using a serialization framework. I have used [Protobuf.net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) and this [does support references/object cycles](http://loyc.net/2013/protobuf-net-unofficial-manual.html). I would not be surprised if other libraries have similar features, but I have not used them. In most cases serialization frameworks reduces the amount of code and improves runtime performance and flexibility, so unless you have some special need they would be my go to solution.

Comment: I totally agree with you about using already existing frameworks and converting to regular list,but I can't use them and I need to preserv the random node. The thing is, this task was a test for job. Unfortunately, they said, that my solution is not good, without specifying what is wrong with my code. And this problem is really bugging me out, so I want to know how to improve this solution.

Comment: @luckydemon The best alternative would be to ask them. I would consider it professional courtesy to provide an explanation when rejecting someones code. You might also consider posting at codereview.stackexchange. If I had reviewed the code I might comment on the usage of `Tuple` rather than ValueTuple, `ElementAt(i)` rather than regular indexer etc. It might also depend on the experience level. The standards for a junior and senior developer might be quite different.